# Copy metadata description field from soundminer to BWAV

Tags: sound, metadata, database, soundminer

I created some metadata in soundminers description field using soundminer 4.5 pro.

But unless i am mistaken that data will not be readable in non-soundminer metadata software that only reads the generic BWAV description field.

Is there a way (osx) to batch copy (thousands of files) the metadata of soundminer's description field to the BWAV description field?

Thanks.
D.

Answer (score 1):

Export Soundminer Metadata fields to text. Import in Excel, copy paste columns.
Save as txt and import back into Soundminer database. Then right click and embed metadata.